# failed to create dump file(error 183) league of legends on litrus. My OS is ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux, lutris

I had LoL running for about a week then I wake up one morning and after the login page it says "failed to create dump file(error 183)". I know a little about errors 183 is when u can't create a new folder that already exists. Meaning that I have old corrupt version of this file that overrides the attempt to create a new dump file. I've tried to reinstall league, reinstall lutris, reinstall wine.I would switch between wine versions and reinstall the game with a different wine version each time. I really can't figure this one out. I did all of this to try and get rid of the corrupt dump file, because I believe this is the issue. If this isn't the problem or if I'm doing something wrong, please let me know. Thank you!

When I run the game from Litrus I get the following log:

```
Running gamemoderun /home/nicholas/.local/share/lutris/runners/wine/lutris-lol-5.5-2-x86_64/bin/wine /home/nicholas/Games/league-of-legends/drive_c/Riot Games/League of Legends/LeagueClient.exe --locale=en_US
Initial process has started with pid 19760
Start monitoring process.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/$LIB/libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/$LIB/libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/$LIB/libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/$LIB/libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/$LIB/libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/$LIB/libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/$LIB/libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
000000.000|   OKAY| Running from cwd 'C:\Riot Games\League of Legends'.
000000.000| ALWAYS| Application Version:11.5.361.5971 - CL:3615971 - Build Date:Feb 26 2021 - Build Time:16:06:51
000000.000|   OKAY| Initial working directory: "C:\Riot Games\League of Legends"
000000.000|   OKAY| Current process: "C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\LeagueClient.exe"
000000.000|   OKAY| Command line arguments:
    --locale=en_US
000000.001|   OKAY| Enabling Data API Dradis collection with endpoint: https://ekg.riotgames.com/messages
000000.006| ALWAYS| The following message is prepared to be sent to dradis:
Event Name: riot__rclient__event
common.os_platform: Windows
common.application_name: LeagueClient
common.application_version: 11.5.361.5971
common.cef_version: 74.1.19+gb62bacf+chromium-74.0.3729.157
common.installation_id: vH5wPA==
common.locale: en_US
common.os_version_major: 10
common.machine_id: 0Dmgxjz3UkiNFk60kXlQxg==
common.os_edition: Ultimate N, x64
common.os_version_minor: 
common.region: NA
common.session_id: 49c23bc0-d267-3248-b8f7-96649b66c964
event_name: startup
crash_reporter: crashpad
000000.006| ALWAYS| Queued Dradis event to be sent.
000000.006| ALWAYS| Direct Launch enabled for league_of_legends.live in environment 'live' for app path 'C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\LeagueClient.exe' and install dir 'C:\Riot Games\League of Legends'
000000.006| ALWAYS| Found associated Riot Client install (c:/Riot Games/Riot Client/RiotClientServices.exe)
000000.040|   OKAY| Launched Riot Client with process 57
000000.040| ALWAYS| Riot Client started. Exiting with the expectation of being restarted (ExitForDirectLaunch).
000005.459|   OKAY| EventCollector: 0 events remaining after thread join
000005.459|   OKAY| Shut down EventCollector in 455 milliseconds
Initial process has exited (return code: 0)
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/$LIB/libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/$LIB/libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/$LIB/libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/$LIB/libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/$LIB/libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
Monitored process exited.
All monitored processes have exited.
Exit with returncode 0
```

To run: `sudo sh -c 'sysctl -w abi.vsyscall32=0' && lutris`

Comment: @guiverc I added more information

Comment: What OS & release are you using?  Ubuntu has multiple products, and currently you've provided no details as to what you're using (we can assume it's desktop, or you've added a desktop, but again on what base?)  Details you've provided thus far look like it's not Ubuntu, but UE-Linux (or UA-Linux) which whilst based on Ubuntu, is not Ubuntu, or *flavor* of Ubuntu).

Comment: @guiverc alright its good now